# assembly language how to compare to null character

Tags: assembly, null, compare, x86-64, att

I am reading one character by one character from an input string, swapping the nibbles of the character, and copy to the output string. so I need a condition to end the loop: my ending condition is that if I am getting a NULL character (stored in rdi), that means that I have reached the end of the input string and I exit the loop. the following is my implementaiton, but I am getting segmentation fault at this line "cmpq 0x00, %rdi".

Note:
r12 is the input string, r11 is the index of the string, rdi is the first input parameter to function "swap", if rdi is NULL character which means that there is no more char in the input string and I exit the loop and do not call swap.

```
loop:
     movq (%r12, %r11, 1) %rdi
     
     cmpq 0x00, %rdi --> this is causing segmentation fault, why?
     je exit

     call swap

     ...

jmp loop

exit:
    leave
    ret
```

can anybody tell me why `cmpq 0x00, %rdi` is causing segmentation fault? how to I check whether a charater is NULL? I thought 0x00 means null character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In AT&T syntax an unadorned number refers to an *address*.  You are comparing `%rdi` to the value fetched from address `0x0`, i.e. you are dereferencing a null pointer.

If you want an immediate, use `$`: `cmpq $0x0, %rdi`.

However if you are looking for a null *character* (i.e. zero byte), your code doesn't make sense because you are loading and comparing an 8-byte qword (`%rdi` is a 64-bit register).  If you want a single byte, use an 8-bit register.  If you like `%rdi`, its low 8 bits are the register `%dil`, but maybe you'd like something like `%al` instead.  So:

```
movb (%r12, %r11, 1), %al
cmpb $0x00, %al
je exit
```

Comment: Normally you'd use `movzbl (%r12, %r11, 1), %eax` to load a byte, and `test %al,%al` to set FLAGS according to its value (but yes that's the same as `cmp $0, %al`).  Or of course you can `cmpb $0, (%r12, %r11, 1)` if you don't have a use for the char in a register later.